# How can I create a dynamic filter

Tags: django, postgresql, django-filters

I Have diferent attributes like brand,size and color

I want a filter to dynamically as per the choice of user

```
Product.objects.filter(attributes__userchoice=some_value).
```

User can select multiple attribute and their values

Example if the user selects size=L the query should be

```
Product.objects.filter(attributes__size='L')
```

Comment: You can create a dictionary and then pass that dictionary to a filter. Like this `query_dict  = {'attribute__size':size}` and then `Product.objects.filter(**query_dict)`

Comment: I literally gave you the answer to this in the previous question. The answer has not changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
p = Product.objects.all()

if brand:
    p = p.filter(attributes__brand=some_value)
if size:
    p = p.filter(attributes_size=some_value)
if color:
   p = p.filter(attributes_color=some_value)
```

or you can check the Django Q() if this is not enough